# Scala cats map EitherT Futures with key->value pairs

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future, scala-cats

I'm a bit stuck, but maybe somebody can help me.

I have a list of id's I want to do an API call on:

```scala
val ids:List[String] = List("id1","id2","id3", "id4")
```

And this api method that returns a `EitherT[Future, CustomError, JValue]`

```scala
def recordById(id: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): EitherT[Future, CustomError, JValue]
```

The code below works as I want: sequencing a list of futures to one future of list

```scala
val action:Future[List[Either[CustomError,JValue]]] = ids.map(
  id => api.recordById(id).value
).sequence
```

But what I *really* want is preserving the id's with the result, like:

```scala
val action2:Future[List[(String,Either[CustomError,JValue])]] = ids.map(
  id => (id, api.recordById(id).value)
).sequence
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was typing the question. Something triggered and I've actually made it work using `traverse` instead of `sequence`

```scala
val action2:Future[List[(String,Either[CustomError,JValue])]] = ids.map(
  id => (id, apiv4.recordById(id).value)
).traverse{
  case (id, etf) => etf.map(et => (id, et))
}
```

This seems to work as I wanted. I'm open to improvements /suggestions

**Edit:**

Suggestion by [Marth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650437/marth)

```scala
ids.traverse(id => apiv4.recordById(id).value.map(id -> _))
```

Comment: I don't think you need the initial `.map`, you should be able to do `ids.traverse(id => apiv4.recordById(id).value.map(id -> _))`.

Comment: Even better. Thanks @Marth